# C++ inlined events undefined during instantiation

Tags: c++, templates, events, callback, inline

I want to create inlined event functions if possible. Storing func pointers in a container isn't a way because they can't be inlined. The code in the event will be called always and I don't want to add it to one global event function.

My code:

```cpp
enum class eGameEvent
{
    LOOP,
    LOAD
};

template<size_t n>
class GameEvent
{
public:
    const static eGameEvent s_event;
    inline static void Event() { }
};

#define GameEvent(t_event)                                                     \
template<> const eGameEvent GameEvent<__COUNTER__>::s_event = t_event;         \
template<> void GameEvent<__COUNTER__>::Event()                                \

class c{};                                                              
std::unique_ptr<c> ptr;

GameEvent(eGameEvent::LOOP)                                                       
{
    //VS: identifier "ptr" is undefined detected during instantiation of class at line
    //but compiles and works as i want
    if(ptr)
    {
         std::cout <<"test\n";
    }
}   

template <std::size_t... Is>
constexpr auto OddIndicesHelper(std::index_sequence<Is...>) 
{
    return std::index_sequence<(2 * Is + 1)...>{};
}

template <std::size_t N>
using OddIndices = decltype(OddIndicesHelper(std::make_index_sequence<N / 2>{}));

template<eGameEvent Event>
constexpr void DeclareEvents()
{
    [] <std::size_t... I>
    (std::index_sequence<I...>)
    {
        (((GameEvent<I - 1>::s_event == Event) ? GameEvent<I>::Event() : [] {}()), ...);

    }(OddIndices<__COUNTER__>{});
}
    
void Loop()
{
    DeclareEvents<eGameEvent::LOOP>();
};

int main()
{
    ptr = std::make_unique<c>();
    
    while(1) Loop();
}
```

The code compiles with v143 MSVC, but if I try to use global variable in an event, I am getting [VS IDE warning](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XHMNY.png): **"identifier "ptr" is undefined detected during instantiation of class at line X"**

It seems to works, but is this code even legal and has defined behavior?
With gcc using the compiler explorer it also compiles without problems.

Comment: This is a weird thing to do. It forces you to put all handlers in a single translation unit, and at that point, can't you make one big `switch`?

Comment: Looks legal to me, MSVC intellisense is buggy. You can try a different IDE, with code completion based on Clangd (VSC can use Clangd), I've never had those issues with it.

Comment: "_Storing func pointers in a container isn't a way because they can't be inlined._": That's not true. If the container is e.g. a `constexpr std::array`, then I am sure compilers will still be able to inline. Example: https://godbolt.org/z/a7PdjG5W9

Comment: Perhaps the IDE gets confused by your code generation macro that has same name as class template. If a tool gets confused by a piece of code then most of human readers (including its author few weeks later) are confused too.

Comment: @ÖöTiib also that may break in clang\gcc. Technically that's not quite legal.

Comment: @user17732522 In your case it can be inlined, but I want to have an interface to declare the event in one place and not add every function I would use to std::array. 
Code like this won't be inlined: [Click](https://godbolt.org/z/d1cG9rKsf)

Comment: Why are you playing all these games with `__COUNTER__`? Why not just have the macro stamp out specializations of `GameEvent<t_event>::Event`? [Like this](https://godbolt.org/z/3esjxsWGr). At which point, you can probably ditch the macro, too; it shaves off just a few characters of typing.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik I want to have multiple event instances of same type in different files.
Something like inlined callbacks/observers, because I won't add new events at runtime.
I could use function pointers or just add my whole code to function like void OnEvent_X(), but I am thinking of getting something more efficient and readable.

Comment: With `__COUNTER__` I can easily declare practically as many events as I want with one line, because every GameEvent(event ) = class static member specialization.
And with optimizations it will be fully inlined.

Comment: Danger, Will Robinson. `__COUNTER__` will start counting from zero in every translation unit. If you define, say, `GameEvent<0>` differently in different translation units, your program will violate the One Definition Rule, thus exhibiting undefined behavior (or perhaps be ill formed no diagnostic required; I always forget which).